# get random password with puppet function

Tags: ruby, puppet

I have a function that allow me to generate random password. My function is working well without a puppetmaster. When I tried with a master an error appear when I called the function :

```
Error 400 on SERVER: bad value for range
```

Here is my function:

```
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
  newfunction(:get_random_password, :type => :rvalue, :doc => <<-EOS
Returns a random password.
    EOS
  ) do |args|
    raise(Puppet::ParseError, "get_random_password(): Wrong number of arguments " +
      "given (#{args.size} for 1)") if args.size != 1
    specials = ((33..33).to_a + (35..38).to_a + (40..47).to_a + (58..64).to_a + (91..93).to_a + (95..96).to_a + (123..125).to_a).pack('U*').chars.to_a
    numbers  = (0..9).to_a
    alphal = ('a'..'z').to_a
    alphau = ('A'..'Z').to_a
    length = args[0]
    CHARS = (alphal + specials + numbers + alphau)
    pwd = CHARS.sort_by { rand }.join[0...length]
    return pwd
  end
end
```

The function is called in both case with `$pwd = get_random_password(10)`.

When I specified the length directly in the function to 10 for example. The password is well generated in master mode.

Have you any idea why I can't specify the length value?

Comment: FYI: For sensitive data like passwords, [`SecureRandom`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) is far better from a security perspective than `sort_by { rand }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear why this works for `puppet apply` (if that's what you're insinuating), but the error is most likely a typing issue.

Try

```
length = args[0].to_i
```

Comment: Hi, I was that. 
I found it 1 hour after I posted the issue and I forgot to update the post here.

Thanks anyway for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

To my Knowledge,For situations like this I use the puppet generate() function to create the random password and store it in a persistent data store on the master.

For instance,an SQLITE database or something.  This way, the password is generated randomly if it does not exist and the same password is used if it does already exist.

It's important to have the resource always be managed, that way if the password is changed on the managed node Puppet will realize this, change it to the value you're managing, and report that it did so.